# "RTLD_NEXT used in code not dynamically loaded" Please help

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I have used dlsym to create a malloc/calloc wrapper in the efence code as to able to able to access the libc malloc (occassionally apart from efence malloc/calloc). Now when i link it, and run, it gives following error: "RTLD_NEXT used in code not dynamically loaded"

```
bash-3.2# /tool/devel/usr/bin/gcc -g  -L/tool/devel/usr/lib/ efence_time_interval_measurement_test.c -o dev.out -lefence -ldl -lpthread

bash-3.2# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tool/devel/usr/lib/

bash-3.2# ./dev.out 

 eFence: could not resolve 'calloc' in 'libc.so': RTLD_NEXT used in code not dynamically loaded
```

Now, if i use "libefence.a" it is happening like this:

```
bash-3.2# /tool/devel/usr/bin/gcc -g  -L/tool/devel/usr/lib/ -static       
efence_time_interval_measurement_test.c -o dev.out -lefence -ldl -lpthread

/tool/devel/usr/lib//libefence.a(page.o): In function `stringErrorReport':
/home/raj/eFence/BUILD/electric-fence-2.1.13/page.c:50: warning: `sys_errlist' is  deprecated; use `strerror' or `strerror_r' instead

/home/raj/eFence/BUILD/electric-fence-2.1.13/page.c:50: warning: `sys_nerr' is  deprecated; use `strerror' or `strerror_r' instead

/tool/devel/usr/lib//libc.a(malloc.o): In function `__libc_free':
/home/rpmuser/rpmdir/BUILD/glibc-2.9/malloc/malloc.c:3595: multiple definition of `free'
/tool/devel/usr/lib//libefence.a(efence.o):/home/raj/eFence/BUILD/electric-fence-2.1.13/efence.c:790: first defined here
/tool/devel/usr/lib//libc.a(malloc.o): In function `__libc_malloc':
/home/rpmuser/rpmdir/BUILD/glibc-2.9/malloc/malloc.c:3551: multiple definition of `malloc'
/tool/devel/usr/lib//libefence.a(efence.o):/home/raj/eFence/BUILD/electric-fence-2.1.13/efence.c:994: first defined here
/tool/devel/usr/lib//libc.a(malloc.o): In function `__libc_realloc':
/home/rpmuser/rpmdir/BUILD/glibc-2.9/malloc/malloc.c:3647: multiple definition of `realloc'
/tool/devel/usr/lib//libefence.a(efence.o):/home/raj/eFence/BUILD/electric-fence-2.1.13/efence.c:916: first defined here
```

Please help me. Is there any problem in linking?

Comment: Does it link against libefence.so or libefence.a?

Comment: There are both, libefence.a as well as libefence.so present in the lib directory. I think until i use -static, it will take .so.

Comment: I am adding the effect, i had using libefence.a

Answer (score 2):

> NO ONE IN STACK OVERFLOW WHO CAN RESOLVE THIS

The problem is with your question, not with us ;-)

First off, `efence` is most likely the wrong tool to use on a Linux system. For most bugs that `efence` can find, Valgrind can find them and describe them to you (so you could fix them) much more accurately. The only good reason for you to use `efence` is if your application runs for many hours, and Valgrind is too slow.

Second, `efence` is not intended to work with static linking, so the errors you get with `-static` flag are not at all surprising.

Last, you didn't tell us what `libc` is installed on your system (in `/lib`), and what libraries are present in `/tool/devel/usr/lib/`. It is exceedingly likely that there is libc.so.6 present in /usr/devel/usr/lib, and that its version does not match the one installed in /lib.

That would explain the `RTLD_NEXT used in code not dynamically loaded` error. The problem is that glibc consists of multiple binaries, which *all must match exactly*. If the system has e.g. libc-2.7 installed, then you are using /lib/ld-linux.so.2 from glibc-2.7 (the dynamic loader is hard-coded into every executable and is not affected by environment variables), and mixing it with libc.so.6 from glibc-2.9. The usual result of doing this is a `SIGSEGV`, weird unresolved symbol errors, and other errors that make no sense.

Comment: I am glad at least someone replied to my question:)

Comment: We don't have a separate /lib. It is either /tool/devel/usr/lib (glibc). Or the /tool/usr/lib (SSlibc). The libc version is probably the libc.so.6 (but i am sorry, i can't confirm you on this since today is a weekend). Request, can you please give some other hint? Also, efence has a static library (libefence.a). What is this meant for, if you say efence is not meant for static linking?

Comment: /tool/devel/usr/lib has all the glibc libraries and also libefence.so as well as libefence.a That is why i gave that path.